# How to replace 'makeIso' from the older lens versions in the new version (4.3)?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have some code which uses `makeIso` from the `lens` package:

```
newtype Foo = Foo Integer
makeIso Foo'

incrementFoo :: Foo -> Foo
incrementFoo = foo +~ 1
```

Now I would like to use this code with the 4.3 version of the `lens` package.
This version lacks `makeIso` and the changelog says:

> Removed `makeIsos` in favor of `makePrisms` and `makeLenses`. Each of these functions will construct `Isos` when appropriate.

Because there never was such a function as `makeIsos` I think it's a spelling mistake and they mean `makeIso`. So I tried to replace `makeIso` by `makeLenses` but that doesn't create a foo `Iso`.

What is the correct way to replace `makeIso`?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define an accessor with an underscore:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

newtype Foo = Foo { _getFoo :: Integer } deriving Show
$(makeLenses ''Foo)
```

This will create a `getFoo` iso:

```
getFoo :: (Profunctor p, Functor f) => p Integer (f Integer) -> p Foo (f Foo)
```

Comment: Presumably `makePrisms` will make `_Foo` instead.